# Pandas : fill values from from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I did a pandas merge and now have two columns - `col_x` and `col_y`. I'd like to fill values in `col_x` with `col_y`, but only for rows where where `col_y` is not `NaN` or has a value. I'd like to keep the original values in `col_x` and only replace from `col_y` if `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'i': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'c': [np.nan, {'a':'A'}, np.nan, {'b':'B'}],
                   'd': [{'c':'C'}, np.nan, {'d':'D'}, np.nan]
                 })
```

Expected output:

```
i    c         d
0  {'c':'C'}   {'c':'C'}      
1  {'a':'A'}   np.nan
2  {'d':'D'}   {'d':'D'}
3  {'b':'B'}   np.nan
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you just trying to fillna?

`df.c.fillna(df.d, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where()`

So something like

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['c'].isna(), df['d'], df['c'])
```

should do the trick! The first parameter is the condition to check, the second is what to return if the condition is true, and the third is what to return if the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["c"] = [y if str(x) == "nan" else x for x,y in zip(df.c,df.d)]
```

Probably cleaner way but this is one line